# GNU octave's mean function

Tags: octave, mean

K guys:
What is the mean of {1, 2, 3}
2 right?
Apparently not:

```
octave:50> B = [1, 2, 3]
B =

   1   2   3

octave:51> mean(B)
ans =

   0.42478
   0.55752
   0.73451

octave:52> B = [1;2;3]
B =

   1
   2
   3

octave:53> mean(B)
ans =

   0.42478
   0.55752
   0.73451
```

Do I just not know what a mean is?

Comment: I suppose you've overridden `mean`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably using a different `mean` function than the default defined in Octave. I have tried your code and get `2` as an answer. To determine this, enter the following command at the octave prompt

```
which mean
```

This is my output

```
`mean' is a function from the file /usr/share/octave/3.4.3/m/statistics/base/mean.m
```

If I define `mean` by entering the following code

```
function retval = mean (v)
   retval = v / e;
endfunction
```

I get a different answer for `mean(B)` when `B = [1, 2, 3]`

```
ans =

   0.36788   0.73576   1.10364
```

If I enter the command `which mean` I now get this

```
`mean' is a command-line function
```